# What did Superman's creators think of his evolution from their vision to the very different modern superhero?

Tags: dc, history-of, superman

The original Superman had fewer and more limited powers (and more vulnerabilities) when Shuster and Siegel first created him. He could not fly and while bullets could not hurt him, a "bursting shell" might.

Everyone knows his current powers. While the pair famously sued over selling the copyright of their character, receiving remarkable compensation, I never read whether they expressed an opinion about how Superman had been changed.

Is it known if they objected to or agreed with the fundamental changes made over the years to Superman?

Comment: Hmm. Well I don't really know how they felt, but i'd like to think that for the most part they'd be proud. He is after all one of the most famous, iconic, heroes of all time. Superman is still supposed to stand for truth and justice and of course "Hope." How do you find something bad with that?

Comment: @MrInfinity - I bet there's room for disappointment. If I were the original writer of Jesus, I would be pretty upset about what modern christianity has done to him, especially in the western hemisphere, regardless of how well received he is by those with good intentions.

Comment: @KaiQing - There's not exactly an original writer of Jesus, of course. The different books of the Christian Bible were written by different people at different times,  most likely based on the life of a real itinerant preacher who would have lived in Roman Palestine in the early first century CE, but (from the perspective of non-religious historiography) would not have been a miraculous healer or God incarnate.

Comment: @Adamant - I'm being facetious. General point being any author tends to dislike when someone edits their creation, no matter how popular it becomes. They may not regret selling the IP, or the general monetary gain they make from their originals, but that doesn't necessarily mean they agree with what had to be done to their work to make it what the world has embraced. Huge points to you for that last line though. Every time I make a snide comment referencing anything about Jesus I am expecting a wealth of auto-defenders racing in to explain how the good lord feels.